# Debugging Flutter in Visual Studio Code since IOS 13 update does not work

Tags: iphone, flutter, visual-studio-code, ios13

When debugging my Flutter app on my Iphone X that was just upgraded to IOS 13, I can no longer see any debugging information, including no console logs. It also only compiled and loaded once, and now it only loads a white screen and never loads.

Have tried using Master channel but didn't work on that either. Used flutter clean, flutter get packages and flutter upgrade on the stable channel and still no luck.

Comment: This is a bug that seems to affect physical devices running iOS 13, see: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41133 There's a post from a Flutter team member 11 days saying it was on his list to look at, so hopefully a fix is on the way.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. If anyone have solution then please help.

Comment: @SheetalKumarMaurya for now I have been running the app in debug then going to view -> command palette -> dart: open observatory. From there you can see the debug logs. Hope that helps you.